# Using a temporary table to query and update existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am still new to using SQL and this query has got me particularly stuck.

I am importing a `.CSV` file into a temporary table (it is only 1 column wide and it imports fine with the exception of the first row which is for some reason blank) for the purpose of updating a table in the existing database upon matching the imported column.

The problem I am having is that it is only matching the last entry in the imported table and doing the update to only 1 record in the existing table. The `.CSV` file is generated from a spread which in turn was generated from a query of the existing DB so I know the names are correct and they are in the temporary table.

I have seen several similar querying problems/solutions and tried to use parts of their solutions to no avail and am hoping that this community can help me out!!

```
if object_id('dbo.namefile', 'u') is not null 
    drop table dbo.namefile

create table dbo.namefile
(
    name varchar(255) not null primary key
    --constraint pk_t1_name check(name not like 'zzzzzzz')
)

bulk insert dbo.namefile
from 'f:\list.csv'
with (datafiletype = 'char',
      fieldterminator = '","',
      rowterminator = '\r',
      errorfile = 'f:\inp_err.log') 

update dbo.MeasurementLimit 
set LowLimit = 1
from namefile as nf
join EntityName as en on en.EntityName = nf.name
join MeasurementLimit as ml on en.uid = ml.UID
where en.EntityName = nf.name
```

Thanks for any help

I tried this, this morning

```
select * from namefile
```

It returned 113 records the correct number of entries in the list.csv file

This however only returned 1 record

```
select * from namefile nf  
 inner join Entityname as en on en.Entityname = nf.listname
```

[Entityname table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWVlw.png)

[Measurementlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaRny.png)

Comment: Is this `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They aren't the same thing.

Comment: SQL Server 2014.. Sorry..

Comment: SQL Server 2014.. Sorry.... the namefile table is just a list of names that need to be changed or updated. it identifies with the entityname column in the entityname table.(see image) then uses the uid column to identify with the measurementlist uid column to identify the particular field I want to update the lowlimit in tis sample (see image) What I expect to happen is when this runs if the name in the temp table matches the name in the entityname table it will update the lowlimit to "1" for the associated name for all names listed in the temp table..

Comment: I apologize if my terminology is incorrect. I also don't have access to image or upload sites so the 2 images are the best I can provide from work for samples

Comment: Last line `where en.EntityName = nf.name` looks at least redundant. Try to build partial `select` query i.e. `select * from namefile` then `select * from namefile nf inner join EntityName as en on en.EntityName = nf.name` and so on and see where rows disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was in the bulk insert.. The original code (above) would read in a single column csv file but it also added a blank record to the table which screwed up any query you would run against it the corrected insert code is

```
bulk insert namefile  
from 'f:\list.csv'  
(  
datafiletype = 'char',  
fieldterminator = ',',  <========= This was wrong  
rowterminator = '\n',<====== and this was wrong  
errorfile = 'f:\inp_err.log'  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is that you are not using an alias for the `update`.  How about this version:

```
update ml
    set LowLimit = 1
from namefile as nf join
     EntityName as en 
     on en.EntityName = nf.name join
     MeasurementLimit as ml
     on en.uid = ml.UID
where en.EntityName = nf.name;
```

Comment: Even doing just a simple select gives me only 1 record and there are 113 in the namefile table (see the added edit above)